# Htaccess file modify so that users with IPs starting with particular pattern can only register but everyone can view the site

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have made a php mysql website where users can register. I want to modify the htaccess file (or any php code to do this) such that only the connection starting with ip x.y.z.v (where v varies) can register to the site but everyone can view the public data of the site. Most users will access the website through wireless connection as I am in a shared college network. [this is the registration url][1]

```
http://localhost/register.php
```

right now it is not on the servers so you can reference this url.

Comment: I think if you put this code into your PHP it will end up being more robust.

Comment: Yes, this definitely should be part of your application.

Comment: The faster you get an unauthorized user out of your stack, the better!

Comment: I did not understand @Matthew what are you trying to indicate sir.

Comment: instead of having your .htaccess file denying access, you could do this check within your php code, this way you can update it a lot easier, do better logic (ie connect to a database to get an updated list of valid ips, deny/allow based on metrics other than ip, etc.).  For the rest of your application, do you just never expose links to `register.php`?  Or is it when a user clicks it, they are given a 403 forbidden?  Doing this sort of thing will give a better user experience for people who do not have access (ie they wouldn't even see a link).

Comment: Okay maybe It could go like this. User opens the registration page and it shows the message that 'only members of this university can register her'. This could easily be done using php's SERVER superglobal ? So no need to modify the htaccess file.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I would make it so regular users would not even know that page existed, the page that has a link to `register.php` would hide the link for users that do not have permission.  The other check (within `register.php`) would do the hard denial.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to obtain the current user's IP address. Simply compare this value to your "approved" addresses. For example, if you wanted to check if the user's IP starts with `10.10`, you could do:

```
$allowed = (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "10.10") == 0);
```

However, I'd strongly discourage using IP-based access control unless you're sure that the "valid" IP addresses will *not* change. As multiple users can appear to have the same IP address (due to [network address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) and IP addresses can often be reassigned, this solution is *not* very secure for any real-world system. (Email tokens, approved registration requests or sign-up codes would be vastly better.)

Comment: I need to allow the registration to the students, staff of only my university and nobody from outside ,so I think that someone using the university wireless IP adress is likely to be member of my university so I think using IP comparison is the best answer for me.
Correct Me IF I am wrong Sir and you can suggest a better method.

Comment: Does your university have a login system for each student and faculty member, or some kind of verifiable piece of information to prove that someone is authenticated? (For example - a student number you can look up in a central database.)

Comment: Yes the university has uid for every student and staff but they will not allow any third party application to access the database.

Comment: An alternative would be to require people to sign in with their @university.tld address, if they have those, so you can confirm they have a working account at the university.

Comment: Acutally the @university.tld address is not given to the students at colleges in India. That is the problem basically that we cannot use any javascript or php to determine the tld using regular expression.Most users will have gmail.com addresses which the university has but can/will not provide to any 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you check PHP's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` value instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Specify your registration page (as a Directory or Location), and you can lock it down:

```
order deny,allow
allow from x.y.z.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use htaccess, you add this to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any other rewrite rules you may have in there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.y\.z\.
RewriteRule ^register\.php - [L,F]
```